# MODX: Is there a way to disable caching for templates completely?

Tags: modx, modx-revolution, modx-templates

I'm developing a site locally with XAMPP. I am using static files for templates, snippets and chunks.

Currently, whenever I update a template file I need to manually clear MODX's cache in the Manager before I see any changes on the front end. This is a bit of a pain and doesnt really work with my task runners.

In the settings area I've turned off:

- Cacheable default
- Enable Script Cache
- Enable System Setting Cache

And turned on

- Disable Global Cache Options

But there is no changes.

Is there some other setting I'm missing?

Is there some CLI commands I could use to do this?

Answer (score 2):

I think you are looking for `cache_resource` setting. You can set it to `No` on your dev environment.

More information: https://docs.modx.com/current/en/building-sites/settings/cache_resource

Answer (score 1):

You can write a gulp task watching for some changes in templates and cleaning Modx cache. Then necessery run it every time you start to work.

Comment: You mean just create a task that deletes everything in the cache directory? Hmm, good idea...